# Telerik Rad Calendar - Is Changing Data Source Possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, calendar, telerik

I'm trying to change the dates displayed in a RadCalendar. For example, I want it to begin 2 weeks before the current date and ends two weeks after the current date. Is it possible?

I was able to change the text displayed in the cells (to display the "new" date) but the "OnClick" methods still sends the "old" date.

OnDayRender I added :

```
e.Cell.Text = "<a href=\"#\">" + _calStartDate.Day.ToString() + "</a>";
_calStartDate = _calStartDate.AddDays(1);
```

But the calendar still thinks that the new dates are the old one, so the "SelectedDate" method returns the "old" date and the date selected is not the current date.

Is there a way to just pass a new list of dates, which would be easier?

**UPDATE / Solution:**

I was able to make it work like that:

```
    private int rowCounter = 0;

    private int rowHeaderCnt = 0;

    private DateTime _startDate;
    private DateTime _endDate;

    private DateTime _calStartDate;
    private DateTime _calEndDate;        

protected void radCalendar_DayRender(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        TableRow tr = (TableRow)e.Cell.Parent;
        Table table = (Table)tr.Parent;

        if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(_calStartDate) < 0)
        {
            ((TableRow)(e.Cell.Parent)).Style["display"] = "none";
        }
        else if (e.Day.Date.CompareTo(_calEndDate) > 0)
        {
            ((TableRow)(e.Cell.Parent)).Style["display"] = "none";
        }
        else if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            // This part will change the week number cell (if you don't display it, hide this part)
            rowCounter++;
            TableCell cellRowHeader = ((TableRow)(e.Cell.Parent)).Cells[0];
            cellRowHeader.Text = rowCounter.ToString();
        }

    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        radCalendar.RangeMinDate = _startDate;
        radCalendar.RangeMaxDate = _endDate;
    }

   protected void radCalendar_HeaderCellRender(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.HeaderCellRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HeaderType == Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.HeaderType.Row)
        {
            rowHeaderCnt++;
            e.Cell.Text = "&nbsp;" + rowHeaderCnt;
        }

        if (e.HeaderType == Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.HeaderType.Column)
        {
            TableRow row = ((TableRow)(e.Cell.Parent));
            row.Cells[0].Text = "&nbsp;" + StringUtil.getStringByLanguage("Week", "Sem.") + "&nbsp;";
        }

    } 


    protected void raCalendar_SelectionChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDatesEventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime startDate = new DateTime();            
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime();
        String url = String.Empty;

        if (e.SelectedDates.Count == 1)
        {
            startDate = e.SelectedDates[0].Date;
            endDate = e.SelectedDates[0].Date;
        }
        else
        {
            startDate = e.SelectedDates[0].Date;
            endDate = e.SelectedDates[e.SelectedDates.Count - 1].Date;
        }

       // ... add code here with startDate and endDate

    }

    public void initCalendar(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        this._startDate = startDate;
        this._endDate = endDate;

        this._calStartDate = startDate;
        this._calEndDate = endDate;

        while (this._calStartDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
        {
            this._calStartDate = this._calStartDate.AddDays(-1);
        }

        while (this._calEndDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
        {
            this._calEndDate = this._calEndDate.AddDays(1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my attempts, you can get very close to this setup. You have to use some trickery though, as the functionality, as far as I can tell, is not built into the calendar to only display the dates as you have asked for.

**On page load:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadCalendar1.RangeMinDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14);
    RadCalendar1.RangeMaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14);
    RadCalendar1.FirstDayOfWeek = (FirstDayOfWeek)DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14).DayOfWeek; 
}
```

**On day render:**

```
protected void RadCalendar1_DayRender1(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.Date >= RadCalendar1.RangeMinDate.Date && e.Day.Date <= RadCalendar1.RangeMaxDate.Date)
    {
        e.Cell.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cell.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

This will get you an initial calendar load that shows 2 weeks back and 2 weeks forward and only allow the user to select inside that date. What it does not do, and I'd guess to be a separate question, is it does not execute the hiding of the dates outside the range when you page to the following month.

[image]

You must be aware that the format for the calendar must be 42 days, as per the design of the tool itself. That is why you see the blank line on top, as we are hiding those days. To my knowledge you can not remove them, only hide them or display them but not allow them to be clicked.

Comment: Thanks, your solution helped me! I was able to hide a complete row like this:  ((TableRow)(e.Cell.Parent)).Style["display"] = "none";
(see updated solution in original post)

Comment: Fantastic, it's always fun to get learned :P. I'll keep that knowledge for next time.